# Use a list to get a value from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several dictionaries that look something like this:

```
myDict = {
    "main": {
        "foo": {
            "xyz": "lorem",
            "abc": "ipsum"
        },
        "bar": {
            "xyz": "dolor",
            "abc": "sit"
        }
    }
}
```

How would I retrieve these values using a given list such as `["main", "foo", "xyz"]` or `["main", "bar", "abc"]` as keys for navigating the nested dictionaries?

**So it would interpret something like `myDict["main", "foo", "xyz"]` as `myDict["main"]["foo"]["xyz"]`**

Comment: You want all combinations or what?

Comment: @AntonvBR No, I'd like to make a function that interprets something like `myDict["main", "foo", "xyz"]` as `myDict["main"]["foo"]["xyz"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
def path_lookup(my_dict, path):
  return reduce(lambda d, ks: d[ks], path, my_dict)

print(path_lookup(myDict, ["main", "bar", "abc"])) # prints sit
```

If you really want dictionaries to respond to tuple indexing as you indicate in your edit, you can make it happen by overriding `__getitem__`, but you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: python3.x so that `print` needs to be wrapped in parens

Comment: if it's python 3, reduce also isn't present and must be imported from functools :/ updating

Comment: How would I set a value like this?

Comment: pop the last key off of the path before you pass it to reduce, store the final dictionary, then do the set operation with the popped key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function like:

```
def lookup(theDict, theKeys):
    val = theDict
    for akey in theKeys:
        val = val[akey]
    return val
```

Comment: yes but we could change val to theDict and overwrite the same value. nice!

Answer (score 1):

Can do like this too:

```
def func(d, l):
    while l:
        d = d[l.pop(0)]
    return d

print(func(myDict,["main","foo","xyz"]))
```

Returns:

```
'lorem'
```

Or like above:

```
def func(d, l):
    for k in l:
        d = d[k]
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using loops:

```
query = ["main", "foo", "xyz"]
myDict = {
    "main": {
        "foo": {
            "xyz": "lorem",
            "abc": "ipsum"
        },
        "bar": {
            "xyz": "dolor",
            "abc": "sit"
        }
    }
}
subdict = myDict
for key in query:
    if key in subdict.keys():
        subdict = subdict[key]
    else:
        print("Invalid query!")
        break
value = subdict
```